# WebApi giving 404 whilst debugging; works when published

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, kestrel-http-server

I have a console application written in .NET Core 2.2.6 that is using Kestrel to host a simple WebApi.

```
public class SettingsController : Controller
{
    // 
    // GET: /settings/

    public string Index()
    {
        return $"Hello world! controller";
    }
}
```

If I publish the code and run the executable, I can visit http://127.0.0.1:310/settings and see the expected "Hello world! controller". However, if I debug (or even open in Release mode) from inside Visual Studio 2019, the same URL throws a 404 exception.

[image: Publish profile]

Some other code that might help pinpoint the problem:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureKestrel((context, options) =>
        {
            options.ListenAnyIP(310, listenOptions =>
            {
                listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http1;
            });
        })
        .UseStartup<Startup>();

public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseDefaultFiles(new DefaultFilesOptions()
        {
            DefaultFileNames = new List<string>() { "index.html" }
        });

        // Return static files and end the pipeline.
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
            {
                const int durationInSeconds = 60 * 60 * 24;
                ctx.Context.Response.Headers[HeaderNames.CacheControl] =
                    "public,max-age=" + durationInSeconds;
            }
        });

        // Use Cookie Policy Middleware to conform to EU General Data 
        // Protection Regulation (GDPR) regulations.
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        // Add MVC to the request pipeline.
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
    }
}
```

Comment: @strickt01: I don't have a launchsettings.json file nor am I using IIS Express. I am using Kestrel. The port number is specified in the code above (`options.ListenAnyIP(310, listenOptions =>`). The connection with the Webserver exists, as I am getting a 404 and I can see the console logging that Kestrel received the request and couldn't find the file.

Comment: @KirkLarkin: <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a very relevant [GitHub issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/8388) that explains what's going on here. Pranav K from the ASP.NET Core team says:

> MVC 2.1.0 requires compilation context to be available. Compilation context tells it if a library references MVC which is used as a filter to skip assemblies that are deemed unlikely to have controllers. Microsoft.NET.Sdk does not set `<PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>` which would explain why you're seeing this.

This means there's a couple of working solutions to the problem you're seeing:

1. Add the `PreserveCompilationContext` property to your .csproj file with a value of `true`, as shown above.
2. Reference the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` project SDK instead of `Microsoft.NET.Sdk`.

I don't know of any perceivable difference between these two options, but I would just update the project SDK given that it is in fact a Web project you're building.