# Adding ASP.NET Core functionality to a .Net Core console application

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have been working with the .Net framework for a long time but have recently begun dabbling with .Net Core.  The ability to integrate ASP functionality into standalone applications is really interesting to me.  I have experimented with porting the functionality of a basic ASP.Net Core application over to a standard .Net Core Console application but have had no success.

I copied the functionality of the main method, the startup class, the controller, and the json config files and I can get the application to run and to listen on the default port 5000, but it refuses to return any data.  The console shows that a request is received so clearly something is listening, but it refuses to pass the request along to the controller and returns a 404.

What am I missing?  How do I get my controller to process the request in a standard .Net Core console application?  Right now I am only testing, but I am concerned that I may need to add functionality to an existing project down the road and it seems backward to have to port everything over to a new project just to add web server functionality

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57251464/webapi-giving-404-whilst-debugging-works-when-published/57292314). It might be a duplicate, but there's not enough information in your question to be sure.

Comment: @KirkLarkin Wow, that actually worked.  That's really un-intuitive, but thank you.  If you put it in an answer I will mark it