# .Net Core How debug routing 404 issues

Tags: c#, .net-core, routes, visual-studio-2017

I have a .net core web api application that I have recently tried to debug (in VS2017) on a new computer (after a long hiatus from working on the app). I also upgraded the .net core from 1.1 to 2.2. However, it no longer seems to route *at all*, even to the ValuesController which I left in for testing purposes, nor with just using localhost (I had been testing it with my local ip address). I've created another web api project (which routes fine) in the same solution and have compared code, config files etc; I've simplified my own code to extreme matching the working web api code:

```csharp
public class Program {

    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

And I've stripped out all but the bare bones of Startup.cs

```csharp
public partial class Startup {
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }


    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) {

        if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        } else {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

```csharp
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
...
```

And made sure my my launchSettings.json also matched my test web api (have tried launching with both the service directly, or via IISExpress). Relevent bit for direct launch:

```
"profiles": {
    "MyWebApiService": {
        "commandName": "Project",
        "launchBrowser": true,
        "launchUrl": "api/values",
        "environmentVariables": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        },
        "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:8080;https://localhost:44385"
    }
}
```

But when it launches, although it first calls http://localhost:8080/api/values, and the redirect to https://localhost:44385/api/values works fine, the call to https://localhost:44385/api/values returns http code 404.

Is there any way to see what is going on in the routing? What it's looking for and where?

Comment: Why did you pass two url's on your "applicationUrl"?

Comment: @MosiaThabo One for https, the other for http. It's what the default test web api does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar problem to [WebApi giving 404 whilst debugging; works when published](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57251464/webapi-giving-404-whilst-debugging-works-when-published) but I hadn't checked the published version. Also, my Sdk as set in the <Project> node in the .csproj file was:

- Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web

as it should be. However, I did have the <PreserveCompilationContext> there and explicitly set to false, which appears to have worked fine prior to v. 2.1. Setting this to true was the solution here:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
        <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
        ...
```

"MVC 2.1.0 requires compilation context to be available. Compilation context tells it if a library references MVC which is used as a filter to skip assemblies that are deemed unlikely to have controllers." See [ASP.NET Core 2.1.0 breaks attribute-routed endpoints in applications targeting Microsoft.NET.Sdk #8388](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/8388)

Note this issue is in all of Microsoft.AspNetCore.App and Microsoft.AspNetCore.All versions 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2 and 2.1.3.

Answer (score 0):

In your code supplied I don't see `AddHttpsRedirection` in `ConfigureServices`. Please add:

```
services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
{
    options.HttpsPort = 443;
});
```

Please refer to: [Enforce HTTPS in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: I have app.UseHttpsRedirection(); in my Startup.Configure method. Also, redirection was working fine, just finding the route at the end wasn't.